# IPV6 socket connect() returns EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: c++, sockets, ipv6

I'm trying to pass the IPv6 support for Appstore, and have some problems.

I followed Apple's Guild [Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW26), my code :

```
const char sAddr[] = "123.123.123.123"; //my IPv4 gamesvr, using boost asio
const char sPort[] = "9899";
const char *cause = NULL;
int sock_;
struct addrinfo hints, *res, *res0;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_DEFAULT;

int error = getaddrinfo(sAddr, sPort, &hints, &res0);
if (error) {
    return false;
}
sock_ = -1;
for (res = res0; res; res = res->ai_next) {
    sock_ = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
    if (sock_ < 0) {
        cause = "socket";
        continue;
    }
    if (::connect(sock_, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
        error = errno; // error = 49, EADDRNOTAVAIL
        break;
    }
    break;  /* okay we got one */
}
if (sock_ < 0) {
    freeaddrinfo(res0);
    return false;
}
freeaddrinfo(res0);
return true;
```

Under IPv4 WIFI, my game runs good.

When switch to IPv6-ONLY WIFI ( run by mac ), functions using CURL runs good, i can obtain web content, but socket connect() failed with errno 49(EADDRNOTAVAIL), res->ai_family = 30 (AF_INET6)

Anyone help me please, many thanks!

Comment: Why do you pass an IPv4 address to `getaddrinfo`? Makes me wonder why this returns anything at all when you switch off IPv4, probably it's just the converted IPv4 address which then does not work without IPv4 network. It would make more sense to use a DNS name there, I guess.

Comment: Apple says, in "Use System APIs to Synthesize IPv6 Addresses",
"If your app needs to connect to an IPv4-only server without a DNS hostname, use getaddrinfo to resolve the IPv4 address literal", my code just follow the sample...

Comment: So your network is IPv6 only, and your server IPv4 only?

Comment: You're leaking sockets like crazy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, though I dunno why...

Surprisingly, when I try to use domain name instead of digital ip address, connection is ok!

**const char sAddr[] = "123.123.123.123"; --> const char sAddr[] = "gs1.mydomain.com";**

my game runs ok under IPv6-ONLY WIFI!

---

Now I'm quite confused why Apple put these into [Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW26) :

```
uint8_t ipv4[4] = {192, 0, 2, 1};
struct addrinfo hints, *res, *res0;
int error, s;
const char *cause = NULL;

char ipv4_str_buf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = { 0 };
const char *ipv4_str = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ipv4, ipv4_str_buf, sizeof(ipv4_str_buf));

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_DEFAULT;
error = getaddrinfo(ipv4_str, "http", &hints, &res0);
```

> Listing 10-1 shows how to resolve an IPv4 literal using getaddrinfo. Assuming you have an IPv4 address stored in memory as four bytes (such as {192, 0, 2, 1}), this example code converts it to a string (such as "192.0.2.1"), uses getaddrinfo to synthesize an IPv6 address (such as a struct sockaddr_in6 containing the IPv6 address "64:ff9b::192.0.2.1") and tries to connect to that IPv6 address.

-_-||

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `break` after `error = errno;` to `continue`. If a `connect` fails you're supposed to try the next address.

The resolver might still give you the original IPv4 result *and* the synthesized IPv6 result for the NAT64. I wouldn't be surprised if the error you're getting is from trying to create an IPv4 socket on an IPv6-only network.

Comment: Please show what exactly you're getting back from `getaddrinfo`